# Knights & Knaves question

Tags: logic

I'm quite confused on how to proceed with this question.

Knights always tell the truth, and knaves lie.

You meet two people, A and B. A says, “I'm a knight
and he's a knave.” B says, “I agree.” What are they?

I'm not sure what to do with B's statement. Since B is a knave, he disagrees with the statement? Is that it?

Comment: What does "I agree" mean when someone who could be a knave says it?  If $A$'s statement is $S$, is $B$'s "I agree" just the same as $B$ stating $S$, or is $B$ stating that $S$ is a statement that $B$ could state?

Comment: A knave would say the first version of "I agree" if and only if statement $S$ is false, but the second form of "I agree" if and only if statement $S$ is true.

Comment: Also, what about the case where $B$ is female?  Does saying "I'm a knight and he's a knave" count as a lie if "he" is not a "he"?

Comment: I think you should add to the question the assumption that each of A and B is either a knight or a knave.

Comment: @ShreyAryan: Why did you delete your answer? It's a good answer; at most a little more explanation of the last step would be helpful.

Comment: make a table of possibilities and eliminate the contradition, what ever is left is the truth

Answer (score 2):

They are two knaves, I mean all other options are clearly false.

---

Since B agrees with the statement, both are claiming that A is truthful and B is contrary.

However if that claim were true, then B would not agree.   So the claim must be false, which means both A and B must be lying.

That is, both are knaves.

Comment: Please elaborate on how you came to this conclusion

Comment: Because: 
 - If they were both knights: B would violate the assumption
 - If A was a knight an B was a knave: B would violate the assumption
 - If A was a knave and B was a knight, B would voilate the assumption
 - Only if they both are knaves can they satisfy the assumptions.

Comment: Btw: Obviously they can both lie, since neither are a knight, as they agree upon.

Comment: So basically I'm looking for the right combination of A and B (knight or knave) such that their assumptions do not violate each other?

Comment: Yes, I proof by exhaustion will do, I'll go through it methodically.
 - Both knights, then B can not agree, since he should always tell the truth
 - A knight, B knave, then B can not agree, since he would then be telling the truth
 - A knave, B knight, then B can not agree, since A is not a knight
 - Both knaves, They're all good the slimy liers!

Comment: This can, of course, also be written more rigorously in a truth table, same technique though.

Comment: Thanks. How would you present the premises on the truth table though, and how would you deduce the conclusion from truth values of the premises? ( A and not B, where A = A is a knight, B = B is a knight).

Comment: Please edit your Answer to contain the additional information/insight presented in your Comments.  One-liners rarely make good Answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. If A is a knight  and said " B is a knave "  This must be true  and a knave  must disagree been a knave.  But B said  "I agree "
   Therefore A is not a  knight. ( If A is not a knight, A must be knave) I can not say A is a knave without taking a look for A been knave.
2. If A is a knave and said " I'm a knight and B is a knave" a knave always lie  and A lied for been a knight and also lied for B been a knave ( this mean B   is a knight)  and a knight always tell truth and can not agree been a knave but B said " I agree "
   Therefore A is not a knave

I conclude that  since A  is neither Knight nor Knave  then the question is INCOMPLETE.
what about Joker who can do either( tell truth or lie)

Then  A is a Joker and B is a knave

Comment: The *single* statement is "I am a knight **and** he's a knave" which will be a lie if A is a knave **or** B is a knight.

Answer (score 0):

B agrees with A. That is, B says: A is knight and B is knave.

Nevertheless, B can't be a knight because knights cannot say they are knaves. They always tell the truth.

However, B cannot be a knave either: Knaves must be lying. If he is a knave and declares to be so, he would actually be telling the truth (liar paradox).

Therefore, since you can't define B, you cant define A either. You don't have enough information.